# Error in xutility when including <string>

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2008, cross-platform, standard-library

Got a very simple C++ VC9 project, it consists of a header file and a source file,

```
#ifndef t_h
#define t_h
#include <string>
std::string foo();
#endif // t_h
```

and

```
#include "t.h"
std::string foo(){return "foo";};
```

Build log for this project is

```
1>t.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xutility(945) : error C2766: explicit specialization; 'std::iterator_traits<size_t>' has already been defined
1>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xutility(877) : see previous definition of 'iterator_traits<unsigned __int64>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xutility(1472) : error C2766: explicit specialization; 'std::_Ptr_cat_helper<size_t*,size_t*>' has already been defined
1>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xutility(1384) : see previous definition of '_Ptr_cat_helper<unsigned __int64 *,unsigned __int64 *>'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xutility(1478) : error C2766: explicit specialization; 'std::_Ptr_cat_helper<const size_t*,size_t*>' has already been defined
1>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xutility(1390) : see previous definition of '_Ptr_cat_helper<unsigned __int64 const *,unsigned __int64 *>'
```

**EDIT**
**In xutility file I have got, these errors are in `#ifdef _LONGLONG` blocks; no idea where `_LONGLONG` is defined.**

Building on 32 platform is fine. Would anyone know how to fix these errors? Thanks.

Project file, in the unlikely event that someone would look into it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<VisualStudioProject
    ProjectType="Visual C++"
    Version="9.00"
    Name="test"
    ProjectGUID="{E9D20D01-C8A4-4477-BD8A-61BB92D3AB77}"
    RootNamespace="test"
    Keyword="ManagedCProj"
    TargetFrameworkVersion="196613"
    >
    <Platforms>
        <Platform
            Name="Win32"
        />
        <Platform
            Name="x64"
        />
    </Platforms>
    <ToolFiles>
    </ToolFiles>
    <Configurations>
        <Configuration
            Name="Debug|Win32"
            OutputDirectory="$(SolutionDir)$(ConfigurationName)"
            IntermediateDirectory="$(ConfigurationName)"
            ConfigurationType="4"
            CharacterSet="2"
            ManagedExtensions="0"
            >
            <Tool
                Name="VCPreBuildEventTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCCustomBuildTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCXMLDataGeneratorTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCMIDLTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
                Optimization="0"
                AdditionalIncludeDirectories=".\.."
                PreprocessorDefinitions="WIN32;_DEBUG;_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS"
                BasicRuntimeChecks="3"
                RuntimeLibrary="3"
                StructMemberAlignment="0"
                ObjectFile="$(IntDir)\"
                WarningLevel="3"
                DebugInformationFormat="3"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCManagedResourceCompilerTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCResourceCompilerTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCPreLinkEventTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCLibrarianTool"
                OutputFile="..\..\..\lib\test_x32_mtd.lib"
                AdditionalLibraryDirectories=""
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCALinkTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCXDCMakeTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCBscMakeTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCFxCopTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCPostBuildEventTool"
            />
        </Configuration>
        <Configuration
            Name="Debug|x64"
            OutputDirectory="$(SolutionDir)$(PlatformName)\$(ConfigurationName)"
            IntermediateDirectory="$(PlatformName)\$(ConfigurationName)"
            ConfigurationType="4"
            CharacterSet="2"
            ManagedExtensions="0"
            >
            <Tool
                Name="VCPreBuildEventTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCCustomBuildTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCXMLDataGeneratorTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCMIDLTool"
                TargetEnvironment="3"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
                Optimization="0"
                AdditionalIncludeDirectories=".\.."
                PreprocessorDefinitions="WIN64;_DEBUG"
                BasicRuntimeChecks="3"
                RuntimeLibrary="3"
                StructMemberAlignment="0"
                ObjectFile="$(IntDir)\"
                WarningLevel="3"
                DebugInformationFormat="3"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCManagedResourceCompilerTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCResourceCompilerTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCPreLinkEventTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCLibrarianTool"
                OutputFile="..\..\..\lib\test_x64_mtd.lib"
                AdditionalLibraryDirectories=""
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCALinkTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCXDCMakeTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCBscMakeTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCFxCopTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCPostBuildEventTool"
            />
        </Configuration>
        <Configuration
            Name="Release|Win32"
            OutputDirectory="$(SolutionDir)$(ConfigurationName)"
            IntermediateDirectory="$(ConfigurationName)"
            ConfigurationType="4"
            CharacterSet="2"
            ManagedExtensions="0"
            >
            <Tool
                Name="VCPreBuildEventTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCCustomBuildTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCXMLDataGeneratorTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCMIDLTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
                Optimization="2"
                AdditionalIncludeDirectories=".\.."
                PreprocessorDefinitions="WIN32;NDEBUG;_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS"
                BasicRuntimeChecks="0"
                RuntimeLibrary="2"
                StructMemberAlignment="0"
                ObjectFile="$(IntDir)\"
                WarningLevel="3"
                DebugInformationFormat="0"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCManagedResourceCompilerTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCResourceCompilerTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCPreLinkEventTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCLibrarianTool"
                OutputFile="..\..\..\lib\test_x32_mt.lib"
                AdditionalLibraryDirectories=""
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCALinkTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCXDCMakeTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCBscMakeTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCFxCopTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCPostBuildEventTool"
            />
        </Configuration>
        <Configuration
            Name="Release|x64"
            OutputDirectory="$(SolutionDir)$(PlatformName)\$(ConfigurationName)"
            IntermediateDirectory="$(PlatformName)\$(ConfigurationName)"
            ConfigurationType="4"
            CharacterSet="2"
            ManagedExtensions="0"
            >
            <Tool
                Name="VCPreBuildEventTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCCustomBuildTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCXMLDataGeneratorTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCMIDLTool"
                TargetEnvironment="3"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
                Optimization="2"
                AdditionalIncludeDirectories=".\.."
                PreprocessorDefinitions="WIN64;NDEBUG"
                BasicRuntimeChecks="0"
                RuntimeLibrary="2"
                StructMemberAlignment="0"
                ObjectFile="$(IntDir)\"
                WarningLevel="3"
                DebugInformationFormat="0"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCManagedResourceCompilerTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCResourceCompilerTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCPreLinkEventTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCLibrarianTool"
                OutputFile="..\..\..\lib\test_x64_mt.lib"
                AdditionalLibraryDirectories=""
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCALinkTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCXDCMakeTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCBscMakeTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCFxCopTool"
            />
            <Tool
                Name="VCPostBuildEventTool"
            />
        </Configuration>
    </Configurations>
    <References>
    </References>
    <Files>
        <File
            RelativePath=".\t.cpp"
            >
        </File>
        <File
            RelativePath=".\t.h"
            >
        </File>
    </Files>
    <Globals>
    </Globals>
</VisualStudioProject>
```

Comment: You got LONGLONG morphed from __int64 into size_t.  Very unhealthy.  Check the date stamp of the files in the vc/include directory and make sure that they are still the original files and were not accidentally edited by an out-of-control Edit+Replace.

Comment: You were right, I have accidentially screwed up one of VC files. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got LONGLONG morphed from __int64 into size_t. Very unhealthy.

Check the date stamp of the files in the vc/include directory and make sure that they are still the original files and were not accidentally edited by an out-of-control Edit+Replace.